# Typescript: How to type an generic object with keys that are array indices?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a generic array were every value can be undefined. So it would be better to use, if i have a object with the indices as key in some cases.

```js
// Simple Example
// bad
exampleFunc<[string, string, string, number, date]>([undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, undefined])
// good
exampleFunc<[string, string, string, number, date]>({"3":  1})
```

My current Typing:

```js
export type DataTypes = string | number | Date;
type ColumnConfigShort<T extends DataTypes> = Partial<ColumnConfig<T>>;
type ToColumnConfigShort<T> = T extends DataTypes
  ? T extends string
    ? ColumnConfigShort<string>
    : T extends number
    ? ColumnConfigShort<number>
    : T extends Date
    ? ColumnConfigShort<Date>
    : never
  : never;

type ColumnsConfigShort<T extends DataTypes[]> = Partial<{
  [I in keyof T]: ToColumnConfigShort<T[I]>;
}>;

type howItCanBeUsed = ColumnsConfigShort<[number, number, string]>;
// howItCanBeUsed = [
//  (Partial<ColumnConfig<number>> | undefined)?,
//  (Partial<ColumnConfig<number>> | undefined)?,
//  (Partial<ColumnConfig<string>> | undefined)?,
// ]
//
// But i need this type:
// dream = {
//   "0"?: Partial<ColumnConfig<number>>;
//   "1"?: Partial<ColumnConfig<number>>;
//   "2"?: Partial<ColumnConfig<string>>;
// }
```

Comment: I don't understand why your first call to `exampleFunc` is *bad*; it meets the same criteria.  I though you just don't want to *require* it to be specified.  Could you elaborate?  Also,  [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/we6PeN) is how I might implement what you're talking about.  It accepts both an actual tuple with `undefined`s as well as `{"3": 1}`, but it rejects anything actually *wrong*.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for. I need to work on my questions so they are understood correctly, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you actually want to *prohibit* someone from passing an array like `[undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, undefined]`, but rather, you'd like to *support* passing a plain object like `{ "3": 1 }`.  If so, then we should write a utility type to turn a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) into a plain [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) equivalent without any of the prototypical array properties:

```
type TupleToPlainObj<T> = { [I in keyof T & `${number}`]: T[I] }

type BaseTuple = [string, string, string, number, Date];
type X = TupleToPlainObj<BaseTuple>;
/* type X = {
    0: string;
    1: string;
    2: string;
    3: number;
    4: Date;
} */
```

That works because we are [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) only the keys of the tuple which are *numeric strings*, which is what the [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) `` `${number}` `` represents (it's a "pattern" template literal type, as described by [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)).

And in your use case you want all those to be optional, so we can use [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype):

```
type Y = Partial<X>
/* type Y = {
    0?: string | undefined;
    1?: string | undefined;
    2?: string | undefined;
    3?: number | undefined;
    4?: Date | undefined;
} */
```

So that means your `exampleFunc()` call signature could look like:

```
declare function exampleFunc<T extends any[]>(arg: Partial<TupleToPlainObj<T>>): void;
```

Which gives the desired behavior:

```
exampleFunc<BaseTuple>([undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, undefined]); // okay
exampleFunc<BaseTuple>({ "3": 1 }); // okay
exampleFunc<BaseTuple>({ "2": true }); // error, boolean isn't string
exampleFunc<BaseTuple>({ "5": "oops" }); // error, extra property
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhGB7ACoghgSwHYDyARgFYA8MAfFALxQDeUA2gJJT5QDWEIqAZrCgAyKAAMAJPTxwAtkQgAnAL6iAugC5YrVVCUAoPaEhQAQlgDOKBMlrNzwBfgDmAGij3HeV+4fO30uUU3ABEsYAhVAG5DcGgADVt4JBQMbHxicjNLJORKaIB6ACooI3jbej0oKqgABk0PZ2jqqABGet8vJuqAJnbPJy6qgGZNAPkFQagAFk1Q8OilKEL8mOMATVt0LAVgHCxEMjjKPSKS2KgNugrmmoB+PucoAB8oODwAEwg+fAh3yZb7j5+s9Xh8vj8-pUeoCGl4QW9Pt88L9JkNAWNFPCwUiUVCqlNAXNoC8EeDkZDFssDJ8AMbYBTQPhvGm7VB4KAQAAeWBkyQAYsyKBzOeEPuYoFg8CAmKpKAAKbZOTRbHZ7A45FKYXCEUgUSiUACUmgAbqgcJC9FyefzBVkrMl5UxSTj3m5nRC3diPa1PYiIaoDdErbzkAK8DSyHaNfLGAAiIaxzQtXSBy3ckMQMMRqPWCAxqCx7qJkoKODQJSBqD5fIchQKVAKNxEVCoZCS9jmPAAcmAQOcaetodtFntuTlcYArMXYy2wOZYynIlWa4p643hQ4sFAwPXIDsQEA)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the [Record<Keys, Type>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) type that represents an object whose keys are of type `Keys` and values are of type `Type`.

For example,

```js
const arrayLikeObject:Record<string, number>  = {"3": 1};
```

While this is not completely type safe as it will also allow keys that aren't essentially *numbers as strings*, I'd advise keeping that keys as numbers instead of strings. That way, the Type of the object will be more strongly typed.

```js
const arrayLikeObject:Record<number, number>  = {3: 1};
```